# How to I launch the AVD from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I'm following the tutorial on creating an android application...
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html

It says: "click Android Virtual Device Manager from the toolbar."

I don't have this button on my toolbar - does the toolbar change depending on what you have got open or something?
I also cant find this command in the menu (inc under Menu > Windows).

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04, eclipse 3.7.2

maybe the tutorial is out of date because I don't have a run button on the toolbar either (the nearest thing is 'launch external tools')

Comment: Have u installed the ADT plugin properly?

Comment: I did install it. How do I check if it is installed properly?

Comment: are u able to see Android SDK manager atleast?

Comment: Do you mean from Eclipse? I can get to android SDK by typing in a command at the terminal

Comment: If you cannot see any of these options under your windows option then you do not have the ADT plugin installed (correctly at least).

Comment: follow this link : http://lbkvutechblog.wordpress.com/2011/12/10/install-eclipse-android-sdk-adt-plugin-on-ubuntu-11-10/ to set up your eclipse for android development in ubuntu. or this link if you have downloaded ADT bundle http://www.liberiangeek.net/2013/02/install-android-sdk-adt-bundle-in-ubuntu-12-10-quantal-quetzal/

Comment: I reinstalled the ADT plugin, everythign went as described in the guides, but I still cant see the button or menu option. Also Under Menu > Projects > The 'Open Projects' is greyed out even though I previously created 2 other projects. Maybe there is some incomparability between the tools, though I used the SDK/Eclipse bundle. Do I need to set up any paths or anyting?

Answer (score 0):

From the link below, see the Icon of this on the topmost left corner. It should be visible if you have correctly installed the plugin and [create](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/index.html) a virtual device.

http://developer.android.com/images/screens_support/avds-config.png

Comment: Can you tell me how to check what plugins are installed please?

Comment: This tells me how to install it but I cant figure out how to check if it has installed properly. If I go Help > Install New SOftware, it is not listed.

Comment: Re-install it anyway. It's not normal that it's not visible.

Comment: I reinstalled the ADT plugin, everythign went as described in the guides, but I still cant see the button or menu option. Also Under Menu > Projects > The 'Open Projects' is greyed out even though I previously created 2 other projects. Maybe there is some incomparability between the tools, though I used the SDK/Eclipse bundle. Do I need to set up any paths or anything?

Comment: Ok, chech here: http://jayxie.com/mirrors/android-sdk/sdk/eclipse-adt.html - check there "modify your Eclipse preferences to point to the Android SDK directory" - you should point where the SDK is.

Comment: Yes had done that - I have a list of things under 'target name' so it looks like the sdk can be found.

Comment: I don't know what else can be besides restarting the Eclipse, which I asume you already did. May be try full removal and then full re-installation, something is fishy here.

Comment: yes, i even rebooted the pc. I will scrap everything and start again. Thanks for you help. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I copy from here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/avd-manager.html

```
 You can launch the AVD Manager in one of the following ways:

In Eclipse: select Window > AVD Manager, or click the AVD Manager icon in the Eclipse toolbar.
In other IDEs: Navigate to your SDK's tools/ directory and execute android avd.
```

I think if you can build android project ,and you have install adt plugin.
I suggestion you could use adt-bundle, not native eclipse:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/bundle.html

Comment: These two ways are the ways I have said in my question that do not seem to be available to me

Comment: you install adt-plugin? and setting android sdk path correctly? if you can build android project ,I guess you do right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly install the Android SDK plugin for eclipse or in alternative have you install the [Eclipse Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)?

If you have done this, from Eclipse go to **Window -> Customize Perspective** then select the third tab **Command Groups Availability** and check **Androdi SDK and AVD Manager**. THIS WORKS FINE FOR ME.